# htaccess redirect subfolder to root

Tags: htaccess

In the following scenario, example.com is my homepage.

I need to:

- redirect `www` to `non-www`
- redirect `index.html` to homepage
- redirect `example.com/store` to `example.com`

This is my htaccess code

```
# Switch rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Do index.html to root redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/$ http://example.com
```

This seems to work except it only redirects `example.com/store/` (with forward slash after store) to the homepage. It does not redirect `example.com/store` (without forward slash)

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/$ http://example.com
```

> it only redirects `example.com/store/` (with forward slash after store)

Which is exactly what the "forward slash after store" is saying in your `RedirectMatch` pattern. However, you should not mix `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) with `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) redirects. Different modules execute at different times, so the outcome can be unexpected.

So, instead, with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^store$ / [R=301,L]
```

This assumes there are no *other* URLs that start `/store`.

(Although, do you want to redirect all requests for files in that subfolder as well? ie. `/store/some-file.php` to `/some-file.php`? ... However, the pattern in your example `^/store/$`, which you said "seems to work", also prevents this.)

---

```
# Do index.html to root redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Bit of an aside, but you also need to escape the `.` (literal dot) in `index.html`. ie. `/index\.html` in both the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives. Also, the `^.*` at the start of your `RewriteCond` pattern is superfluous and can simply be removed. You also don't really need to specify an absolute URL in the substitution (although some do argue that this can avoid potential pitfalls later). So, this becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not create example.com/store/imdex.php and have one line of code

```
header("Location:../index.html");
```

Or if for some odd reason you can't create a php script, do a meta refresh

```
   <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://example.com'>
```

Comment: I would not suggest meta refreshes though, not good for search engines.

Comment: Bit harsh, there was no mention of search engines in the original question, just how could it be done.  This is one way.